# Navigation Drawer in Fragment or Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation

I am trying to add a navigation drawer to an activity which will contain one or two fragments.  I would like this activity to have a navigation drawer associated with it regardless of how many fragments are displayed.  To do this i figured I'd need two xml files, one for the activity and one for the fragment. This seems to work except for the fact that the when the navigation drawer is opened, it is "under" the normal content view.  Am I doing something wrong?  or is there a way to increase the z index of the drawer?

Here is my onCreate() in the activity,

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm_list);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, new AlarmListFragment());
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

and here are my xml layouts:

Activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/alarm_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>

<ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#111"/>

  </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I'd appricate any suggestions on how to go about this!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I wonder how the code is working for you. The above code should not work. You put the fragment at `android.R.id.content`. But I don't see that inside the `DrawerLayout` your Activity XML. Furthermore, the Drawer Layout should only have a `FrameLayout` (with id  'content' in your case) and a `ListView` as mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html). So you need to have add a `FrameLayout` as below in your Activity XML for which you are implementing the navigation drawer.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Also you will have to move the xml into another fragment which you can load when the activity starts or when desired.

Comment: This is true.  I made that fix, and the nav drawer still goes under the rest of the content.

Comment: Make sure you only have a `FrameLayout` and `ListView` inside your `DrawerLayout` as mentioned in the link in my answer.

Comment: That is true.  The drawer is added correctly.  I just am curious as to why it goes under the fragments content.  Since the fragment view is added second does that go on top?

Comment: Its hard to understand what the problem is because the code you have posted is clearly different than what you have running since you say that it works for you!